# Missing element in the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, undefined

This function should create and display an array with numbers. There is some element missing which prevents this array from displaying and so fulfilling the "console.log" assumptions:

```js
function createArray(number) {
    var newArray = [/*10*/];

    for(var counter = 1; counter <= number; counter++) {
        newArray.push(counter);
    }
}

console.log("table with numbers up to 6 = " + createArray(6));
console.log("table with numbers up to 1 = " + createArray(1));
console.log("Testing negatives (should display an empty array) " + createArray(-6));
console.log("Testing 0 (should display an empty array) " + createArray(0));
```

Could you analyze this and provide some feedback, please?

Comment: you may either add `return newArray;` to the end of your function or move `var newArray = [];` assignment instruction out of the function.

Comment: Good point, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `return newArray;` at the end of the function. If there's no `return` statement, the function returns `undefined` by default.

```js
function createArray(number) {
    var newArray = [/*10*/];

    for(var counter = 1; counter <= number; counter++) {
        newArray.push(counter);
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log("table with numbers up to 6 = " + createArray(6));
console.log("table with numbers up to 1 = " + createArray(1));
console.log("Testing negatives (should display an empty array) " + createArray(-6));
console.log("Testing 0 (should display an empty array) " + createArray(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing wrong with your function, just you are not returning the array created, just add:

`return newArray` at the end of the function, linke this:

```
function createArray(number) {
    var newArray = [/*10*/];

    for(var counter = 1; counter <= number; counter++) {
        newArray.push(counter);
    }
     return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes one is thinking so much that cannot see what is obvious... :)